# C# dicom printscu grayscale

Tags: c#, printing, dicom, grayscale

i am looking for a convenient way to print grayscale dicom files from C# to a dicom printer, so basically i am looking for a printSCU. i tried the BasicGrayscalePrintScu from ClearCanvas, but the resulting prints were way to dark and i could not fix it even though i tried all possible parameters. also if the library would provide for annotations it would be great. thanks for any help.

best,
makro

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at mDCM: https://github.com/rcd/mdcm - ClearCanvas is based on mDCM, thus proides a bit lower level access to things and may allow more tweaking to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Printing to DICOM is not as straightforward as you might think.  There are consideration of scaling and colorspaces that require some adaptive canvas manipulation.  You can most certainly find examples of how this looks in DCMTk (C++), and I hear that [fo-dicom (C#)](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom) is starting to support print SCU.

Or, you can pre-render and use a print/drop-folder route, with a tool like DICOM Printer 2 (http://fluxinc.ca/medical/dicom-printer/).  It includes its own XML syntax for annotations, which end up being endpoint agnostic.  Annotation is variably supported across dry imagers, so even if you managed to implement that part, the results would be somewhat unpredictable, unless you chose to use a single model of imager.